# can an arbitrary set be.always embedded in other set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For an arbitrary set $A$ does always exists a set $B$ such that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$? No axiomatic model is specified for this question

Thanks

Comment: Maybe proper subset of B, or maybe specify distinctness? Because A is always a subset of A, isn't it?

Comment: If your set theory has a ZF-style axiom of separation, then you can use an argument based on Russell's paradox. If your set theory has a ZF-style axiom of regularity, you can use that rather directly. If your set theory has neither, you'll have to say what it *does* have.

Comment: You have to assume something, "no axiomatic model" makes no sense. In Quine's NF, there is a set of all sets, so of course what you ask is not possible. In less fringe systems, such as the standard ZFC, this is immediate from Cantor's result that $|x|<|\mathcal P(x)|$.

Comment: It clearly says no specified, not don't asume any model.

Comment: The question is still too vague.

Answer (score 4):

Every set is a subset of itself. I'm assuming, if so that you are interested in a *proper* subset. That is to say that $A\neq B$ as well.

If one assumes the usual axioms of set theory (i.e. $\sf ZFC$) then one can show that $A\notin A$, for every set $A$. In that case $B=A\cup\{A\}$ is such set.

In naive set theory, one can consider the fact that there is no surjection from $A$ onto $\mathcal P(A)$, as Cantor's theorem tells us, in which case $A\cup\mathcal P(A)$ ensures that this is a strictly larger set.

However, if one allows a universal set, i.e. a set of all sets (like the Quine's New Foundation theory), then one can show that not every set is a proper subset of another. As the universal set cannot be a proper subset of any other set.

Comment: Is Choice needed to conclude no set is an element of itself?

Comment: @DavidMitra No, just the [axiom of foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: @David: No, the axiom of choice is consistent with the existence of sets of the form $x=\{x\}$ (of course the axiom of foundation must fail in such model).

Answer (score 1):

Naively, if you want to find an injection from $A$ to a bigger set, remark that $\iota: x \mapsto \{x\}$ is always an injection from $A$ to $P(A)$ and this cannot be surjective since $\emptyset \in P(A)$ is not in the image of $\iota$.